# Get outer class name for an inner class Method Declaration using JDT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I can get the class name for each method declaration in Java by using eclipse JDT. So, for a method declared in an inner class, I get the name of the inner class.

Is it possible to get the **outer class name** for a **method declared in an inner class** by using JDT.

So far, I'm able to identify whether a class is an inner class or outer class by the following code:

```
public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration td) {
    className = td.getName().getFullyQualifiedName();
    if (!td.isPackageMemberTypeDeclaration()) 
            System.out.println(className+" is inner class")

    return true;
}
```

- As I know the inner class name, so is it possible to get it's outer class name by the AST?
- Is there any way to get which .java file the AST parser is processing currently (when a full project is being parsed)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure if this is the ideal way, but you can use the below snippet to get the topmost `TypeDeclaration` (Outer class).

   ```
   public static ASTNode getOuterClass(ASTNode node) {

       do {
           node= node.getParent();
       } while (node != null && node.getNodeType() != ASTNode.TYPE_DECLARATION
               && node.isPackageMemberTypeDeclaration());

       return node;
   }
   ```

   Then you can get the class name by:

   ```
   ASTNode outerClassNode = getOuterClass(methodDeclarationNode);
   if (outerClassNode != null) { // not the topmost node
        System.out.println(outerClassNode.getName());
   }
   ```
2. Usually I pass the `CompilationUnit` as a constructor argument for the `ASTVisitor` class, and get the file name from same.

**UPDATE:**

Another way to get the declaring class details:

```
typDeclarationNode.resolveBinding().getDeclaredTypes();
```

This will return null, if it is a Top-level class. For inner class, it will return the Outer classes.

Comment: I may be missing something but surely you can just use typeDeclarationNode.resolveBinding().getDeclaringClass() ?